# how can i add 2 textfields in the same row and make some space between them flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, row, textfield

how can i add 2 `textfields` in the same `row` and make some `space` between them like this :

Column(
Row(
textfield1(),
textfield2()
)

);

Comment: Try using `SizedBox` with custom width or a `Spacer()` widget

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work by adding the text fields to Expanded widgets

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: TextField()),
        SizedBox(width: 16),            // Use this to add some space
        Expanded(child: TextField()),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: is this make space between them in the same row

Comment: @imeene exactly.